# Compile R presentation in base R

Tags: r, knitr

I have created some R presentations using R Studio, but for a variety of reasons cannot access R Studio to compile them from time to time.

Edited to add:  R presentations are kept in .Rpres files, and are described here:  https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations

Is there a way to compile these using base R only - or perhaps some combination of command line tools?

Comment: Please add code and data to your question in order to attract visibility

Comment: RStudio is just a front end. It still runs all the usual tools in the background. And no, base R (if by "base R" you mean a pure R installation without any additional packages or tools) is not sufficient.

Comment: I don't think base R will work here. You will definitely need packages. I'd look into `rmarkdown`, which has a function `slidy_presentation` which I think is used to produce an html presentation and `beamer_presentation` which is used to produce beamer (Latex) presentations.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replicate Knit HTML in a command line?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27246746/how-to-replicate-knit-html-in-a-command-line)

Comment: by base R i meant the R GUI (including packages): my aim was to distinguish between R and RStudio.  I am not always able to access RStudio (IT security reasons).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to say what format of presentation you have created.  If it is R Markdown in `filename.Rmd`, you would use `rmarkdown::render("filename.Rmd")` to render it.    There are lots of optional parameters; see the help page.

Edited to add:  I can't see any documented way to do this for .Rpres files.  However, you could convert one of those to R Markdown using [Convert RStudio presentation (.Rpres) to rmarkdown presentation (.Rmd)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25791967/convert-rstudio-presentation-rpres-to-rmarkdown-presentation-rmd), and then use the R Markdown method above.

Comment: The type of presentation is an R Presentation -- as described here: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486468-Authoring-R-Presentations